# AccessDeniedException on CloudWatchEvents.putRule()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

What is the right policy i have to attach to an iam user to use `CloudWatchEvents.putRule()` ?

i tryed **CloudWatchFullAccess** and **CloudWatchEventsFullAccess**, both give me an AccessDeniedException for my webclient.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/permissions-reference-cwe.html), `events:PutRule` should be sufficient, but this is also covered by `CloudWatchEventsFullAccess`. Can you post the policy you're using and the exception stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this.  If your policy does not have a region set for the arn allowing PutRule, you will get this 400 Access Exception.  Set region to '*' or your specific region.